# Get YouTube videos in specific day and region

Tags: python-3.x, youtube-data-api

The specific information that I want to get is the list of videos that were most viewed in Senegal. It would be awesome if I can also get the statistics of each video (such as the number of views, likes, dislikes, and comments).

I tried some coding with Python using YouTube Data API v3, but the results seem very different from what I expected. The title of some videos in the results are written in Arabic or Russian, even though their region code is KR; I have no idea what's happening.

The following is my code. Any comments would help. Thx!!

```
import pickle
import os

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from google.auth.transport.requests import Request

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.pickle.
#SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly']
CLIENT_SECRET_FILE = 'code_secret_client.json'
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.force-ssl']
res = []

def get_service():
    """Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.
    Prints the names and ids of the first 10 files the user has access to.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.pickle stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.pickle'):
        with open('token.pickle', 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)

    return build('youtube', 'v3', credentials=creds)


def main():
    youtube = get_service()
    res = youtube.videos().list(
        maxResults='20',
        part="snippet,contentDetails,statistics",
        chart="mostPopular",
        regionCode="SN"
    ).execute()
    return res
    
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 3):

When you talk about videos most viewed in Senegal, are you referring to the most popular video viewable in Senegal, or the most popular video uploaded from within Senegal? These two concepts are very different. The former implies all the video accessible to IP addresses originated from Senegal. If Senegal does not have strong censorship, that would mean videos of the entire world. The latter implies only the videos uploaded from IP addresses within Senegal (or maybe via content owner's metadata, I am not quite sure about this), which would result in much fewer videos.

If you want the first scenario, your code looks fine and the result is not completely strange - people in Senegal might be interested in videos in Russian or Arabic.

But if you want the second scenario, you cannot use `regionCode`. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list#regionCode):

> The `regionCode` parameter instructs the API to select a video chart available in the specified region. [...]

Instead, you will have to use a different API `search().list()` and supply arguments for `location` (GPS coordinates) and `locationRadius`, and order by view count (see its [documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list)). This will return videos uploaded from within Senegal. Then you call `video().list()` on the videos thus returned to collect more information.

Below is a tested Python3 script that pulls videos from a specified location and print out the video title, channel title, published date, and basic statistics of the most popular videos from that location. The script is copied and adapted from [YouTube's API samples](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/blob/master/python/geolocation_search.py). You must supply an API key from your Google Developers Console project that enables "YouTube Data API v3" to use this script.

```
# This sample executes a search request for the specified search term.
# Sample usage:
#   python geolocation_search.py --q=surfing --location-"37.42307,-122.08427" --location-radius=50km --max-results=10
# NOTE: To use the sample, you must provide a developer key obtained
#       in the Google APIs Console. Search for "REPLACE_ME" in this code
#       to find the correct place to provide that key..

import argparse

from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError


# Set DEVELOPER_KEY to the API key value from the APIs & auth > Registered apps
# tab of
#   https://cloud.google.com/console
# Please ensure that you have enabled the YouTube Data API for your project.
DEVELOPER_KEY = 'REPLACE_ME'
YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME = 'youtube'
YOUTUBE_API_VERSION = 'v3'


def youtube_search(options):
    youtube = build(YOUTUBE_API_SERVICE_NAME, YOUTUBE_API_VERSION, developerKey=DEVELOPER_KEY)

    # Call the search.list method to retrieve results matching the specified
    # query term.
    search_response = youtube.search().list(
        q=options.q,
        type='video',
        location=options.location,
        locationRadius=options.location_radius,
        part='id',
        order='viewCount',
        maxResults=options.max_results
    ).execute()

    search_videos = []

    # Merge video ids
    for search_result in search_response.get('items', []):
        search_videos.append(search_result['id']['videoId'])
    video_ids = ','.join(search_videos)

    # Call the videos.list method to retrieve location details for each video.
    video_response = youtube.videos().list(
        id=video_ids,
        part='snippet,statistics'
    ).execute()

    # Add each result to the list, and then display the list of matching videos.
    for video_result in video_response.get('items', []):
        print('Title:', video_result['snippet']['title'])
        print('Channel Title:', video_result['snippet']['channelTitle'])
        print('Published Date:', video_result['snippet']['publishedAt'])
        print('Statistics:')
        for k, v in video_result['statistics'].items():
            print(f'\t{k}: {v}')
        print('---------------')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument('--q', help='Search term', default='Google')
    parser.add_argument('--location', help='Location', default='37.42307,-122.08427')
    parser.add_argument('--location-radius', help='Location radius', default='5km')
    parser.add_argument('--max-results', help='Max results', default=25)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    try:
        youtube_search(args)
    except HttpError as e:
        print('An HTTP error %d occurred:\n%s' % (e.resp.status, e.content))
```

The command to run the script is:

```
python3 youtube_search.py --location "14.627746, -14.597025" --location-radius "200km" --max-results 10
```

In the command, `14.627746, -14.597025` is the GPS coordinates and `200km` the radius for Senegal I eyeballed from Google map. The output from my console is like this:

```
Title: Comment récupérer son compte Google quand on a tout oublié en Wolof
Channel Title: CTGHT
Published Date: 2019-03-17T23:13:16Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 21822
    likeCount: 404
    dislikeCount: 39
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 82
---------------
Title: Comment récupérer son mot de passe compte Google en wolof? méthode 2020
Channel Title: CTGHT
Published Date: 2019-03-11T08:49:35Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 18941
    likeCount: 420
    dislikeCount: 45
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 59
---------------
Title: Comment sauvegarder ses photos et ses vidéos dans son compte Google en wolof?
Channel Title: CTGHT
Published Date: 2019-04-27T15:52:49Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 18145
    likeCount: 813
    dislikeCount: 12
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 109
---------------
Title: Comment créer son compte Google en wolof? méthode 2020
Channel Title: CTGHT
Published Date: 2019-03-05T07:45:59Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 1188
    likeCount: 48
    dislikeCount: 3
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 5
---------------
Title: Supprimer le compte Google pour wiko Lenny 5
Channel Title: Abou niewel
Published Date: 2019-11-01T03:38:37Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 1042
    likeCount: 4
    dislikeCount: 0
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 0
---------------
Title: COMMENT SUPPRIMER LE COMPTE GOOGLE  DE ITEL A14 ET  SUR D'AUTRES ITEL SANS ORDINATEUR
Channel Title: BABZO GB INFORMATICIEN
Published Date: 2019-12-25T00:50:30Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 888
    likeCount: 22
    dislikeCount: 1
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 8
---------------
Title: qu'est-ce qu'un compte Google en Wolof ?《Lane moy compte google?》
Channel Title: CTGHT
Published Date: 2019-03-05T07:43:31Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 754
    likeCount: 40
    dislikeCount: 0
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 1
---------------
Title: Comment créer une classroom sur Google?
Channel Title: Balde Bora
Published Date: 2020-04-18T01:45:11Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 435
    likeCount: 72
    dislikeCount: 0
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 0
---------------
Title: Adafri | Comment Faire de la  publicité sur Google par mobile money
Channel Title: Adafri
Published Date: 2020-04-16T15:29:13Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 375
    likeCount: 3
    dislikeCount: 0
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 0
---------------
Title: Comment télécharger des statuts et vidéos Instagram, Whatsapp,Facebook,YouTube, Twitter, Google...
Channel Title: medza medza
Published Date: 2020-04-17T18:40:56Z
Statistics:
    viewCount: 440
    likeCount: 22
    dislikeCount: 0
    favoriteCount: 0
    commentCount: 1
---------------
```

Comment: thanx for you answer.
I want get the most popular video uploaded from within Senegal and if it is possible to filter on the types of video (music).
I tested your code but it sends me all videos from Senegal but I want to exclude documentaries and films in the search

Comment: Try to add `topicId='/m/04rlf'` in `youtube.search().list()` and see if the output is what you want. According to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/search/list#parameters), `topicId` can retrieve bunch of music topics. If this doesn't work the way you would like, you can try passing in a search query such as `python3 youtube_search.py -q music --location "14.627746, -14.597025" --location-radius "200km" --max-results 10`